# Parent bind boolean but child recive number

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

I don't know how to explain... I have this component:

```
<template>
    <base-layout>
        <template #main>
            <principal-layout>
                <template #dreta>
                    <dot-spinner :is-loading="isLoading"></dot-spinner>
                    <seleccio-estudis :estudis="estudis" @crearsolicitud="crearSolicitud"></seleccio-estudis>
                </template>
            </principal-layout>
        </template>
    </base-layout>
</template>
```

with script

```
...
data() {
    return {
        isLoading: false,
    }
},
methods: {
    crearSolicitud(estudis_id) {
        console.log(typeof(this.isLoading));
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.isLoading = setTimeout(() => {
            this.isLoading = false;
        }, 3000);
...
```

And at child component:

```
<template>
    <div class="vld-parent">
        <loading :active.sync="isLoading"
                    :can-cancel="false"
                    :is-full-page="true"
                    :loader="'dots'" :color="'#58b033'"
                    :width="320" :height="320"></loading>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Loading from 'vue-loading-overlay'
    import 'vue-loading-overlay/dist/vue-loading.css'

    export default {
        components: {
            Loading
        },
        props: {
            isLoading: Boolean,
        },
    }
</script>
```

All works fine, when click on button, loader pop up and discarted after 3 seconds after, but I recive this at console:

> boolean  2 app.js:41533 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed
> for prop "isLoading". Expected Boolean, got Number with value 15.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at resources/js/Components/Layout/DotSpinner.vue
>  at resources/js/LayoutsNous/PrincipalLayout.vue
>  at resources/js/LayoutsNous/BaseLayout.vue
>  at resources/js/Pages/Proves/Home.vue

Every time i reload the page, the value is 15, but every time i click button that emit the event, value grow up one or two units.

Any idea what's happening? I'm doing the same in other components and works without warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of `this.isLoading` to your `setTimeout`:

```
this.isLoading = setTimeout(() => {
  this.isLoading = false;
}, 3000);
```

Change this to:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.isLoading = false;
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Yes, true... but, the "conversion" is before this set of instructions!!!